# LocationManager Network or GPS not working on android API 17 (4.2)

Tags: android, locationmanager

I am using LocationManager to Get device location. The App is working fine on API 22 (5.1) both GPS and Network providers, on API 19 (4.4) only Network provider works fine.
I need to use LocationManager and not Google API As my target Doesn't support google play services.

Does anyone has any idea why Network Provider doesn't work? I can understand GPS may not work due to not getting any signal, but network provider why is it not working in android  API 17 (4.2). Wifi is working fine.